# Remoting HTTPD Centos 7

Tags: apache, ftp, centos, httpd.conf, centos7

I'm using latest **Centos 7 Minimal** with CLI as web server.
Web Server using **httpd**, and Database Server use **MySql**.
I use **vsftpd** as FTP server from Windows to make me easy remote file and directory in that Centos.
But I have a problem that **vsftpd** as FTP server cannot log in as *root*, so it's only directed into **/home/[user]** directory. But I need FTP access to the  **/var/www/html** directory that contain all web files.

What should I do?

1. Any other way that I can use FTP access other than in */home/[user]*?
   or
2. Any other way that I can use to make default httpd DocumentRoot other than */var/www/html*? (I already change **httpd.conf** *DocumentRoot* but it says *"You don't have permission to access / on this server."*)?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you enable  root FTP login and try to upload your file to /var/www/html directory with root user. You need to remove root in /etc/vsftpd/ftpusers and /etc/vsftpd/user_list and restart vsftpd on your server to enable root FTP login.

Comment: Only with remove **root** user from /etc/vsftpd/ftpusers and /etc/vsftpd/user_list then I can login into FTP server as **root**?